# Is the tapwater at Walt Disney World fluoridated?

Tags: health, tap-water, disney

I'll be taking my daughter in a few weeks and I'm having trouble figuring out who provides the drinking water and if they add fluoride to the tap water (water consumed during drinking and eating) or not.

Comment: Specifically the drinking water from water fountains and such? Or the water in fountains and water rides too?

Comment: I imagine if the water rides are then everything is, but that's not my main concern, not much I'm going to do to avoid that.  I'm more concerned with the water we'll be drinking and having our food prepared in.

Comment: @hortstu: You should really include all relevant details in your question. Many places with hot climates are short of water and will use recycled water in their gardens and such but not for drinking. Orlando may well fall into this category.

Comment: Somewhat related meta question: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/412/are-questions-about-controversial-practices-allowed

Comment: @hippietrail my primary concern is water we'll be drinking and eating and my secondary concern is water that will be contacting our skin.  There's not much that can be done about the secondary concern so my question relates to the tap water.  Thanks, I'll edit my question

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, I don't think that question is related.  If you want to consume a chemical that is up to you and may be controversial but if someone wants to avoid a chemical for their own sake or the sake of their child then why is that controversial? Fluoride is not a necessary nutrient. I'm not subjecting my child to malnutrition by avoiding it. I hope some MOD can undo the unnecessary down flag you've added.

Comment: Still, quite apart from the general debate about fluoridation, it might be worth pointing out that it does not seem that a few days of exposure could plausibly make any difference.

Comment: Well I wasn't concerned about myself so much as my young kid.  That being said you decide what your acceptable level of exposure to toxins is and I'll decide what mine is.  Seem fair?

Comment: Based on the behavior of the staff, I'll say "yes"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the [Reedy Creek Improvement District](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reedy_Creek_Improvement_District) provides water for WDW, and they do not add fluoride, but there is roughly [0.10 ppm](http://bit.ly/17RLY5N) of fluoride found in the water.

There are also reports that the water at WDW [tastes horrible](http://www.disboards.com/showthread.php?t=1561435), so you may want to consider bottled water aside from the issue of fluoride.

As a general rule, when traveling, if you are concerned about fluoride, I suggest using a trusted source of bottled water.

Also, unless you or your family suffer from severe fluoride allergies, drinking fluoridated water for a couple days probably won't hurt that much.  Even so, I understand the desire to avoid it.

Comment: Please don't downvote accurate answers to questions, even if you find the question silly.  Besides, the worst thing that can happen from avoiding flouride is more cavities, which is hardly the end of the world.

Answer (score 6):

I've found out that the WDW water provider is [Reedy Creek Improvement District](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reedy_Creek_Improvement_District) and it doesn't seem to fluoridate but there is roughly 0.10 ppm of [naturally occurring/residual fluoride](http://bit.ly/17RLY5N) in the water.  Thanks to all that tried to help.

Comment: This would be better if you include your source.   If it's the better answer at that point, it's OK to mark this as your accepted answer (WRT Flimzy, whose answer is also clearly good/relevant)

Comment: I have edited this answer to contain references, and have also edited my answer to contain this information--not because I want to steal your credit, but because I want my answer to be accurate.  I encourage you to un-accept my answer and accept your own, if you care about getting credit for your own answer research. :)

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks.  You can keep the credit.  I'm sure I'll use this site again, I use other stack sites but I'm not as important to them as the people that are here answering tons of questions like you.  Thanks for the help.